# Finding Date Difference

Tags: java, date

What's the efficient way of finding say if a date is 5 days earlier than another day? Do I need to parse both days using a particular SimpleDateFormat first before I compare?

Comment: 5 calendar days? 5 business days?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
days = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/86400000L
```

Comment: This is maybe the most efficient, but this does not take DST into account.

Comment: -1 That's wrong unless the Date instances were derived from UTC times.

Answer (score 12):

The best Java date time API is [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It makes these tasks, and others, much easier than using the  standard API.

Answer (score 1):

Most quickly, but least accurately, you might just put both into a java.util.Date, getTime() on both, and divide the difference by the number of milliseconds in a day.

You could make it a bit more accurate by creating two Calendar objects, and work with those.

If you really want to solve this well, and have a good bit of time on your hands, look at Joda Time.

Answer (score 1):

The `Calendar` interface has some nice methods, including `before`, `after`, and `equals`.

Comment: The whole API is however fairly epic fail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697215/what-is-your-favourite-java-api-annoyance/1697229#1697229 See for example the calendar example and the jodatime example in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567659/calculate-elapsed-time-in-java-groovy/1776721#1776721

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/DateDiffcomputethedifferencebetweentwodates.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date1 = // whatever
Date date2 = // whatever

Long fiveDaysInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 5    
boolean moreThan5Days = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) > fiveDaysInMilliseconds
```

Comment: You can't just say `date1 - date2`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the calls to 'getTime()' - I've been working with Groovy recently which overloads the '-' operator so you can say `date1 - date2`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Long DAY_IN_MILLIS = 86400000;

if((dateA - dateB) > DAY_IN_MILLIS * 5) {
    // dateA is more than 5 days older than dateB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to *ignore* the time of the dates, you can do something like

```
    public static boolean compare5days(Date date, Date another) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(another);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);

        // clear time 
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return date.before(cal.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

days = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())

Comment: This is not correct since java.util.Date.getTime() returns number of milliseconds. So this difference gives number of milliseconds between date1 and date2.