# How do I calculate the date difference?

Tags: java, android, datetime, date

How to calculate the date difference in Android?

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean by "the" date difference?

Comment: As @Marcare states you need to be more clear.  If you just want to know the number of ms between 2 dates just subtract the Date.getTime() values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't afford 3rd party libraries like [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), then your best bet is really [`java.util.Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). You can use the `Calendar#add()` method in a loop to calculate the difference in years, months and days between two instances. Then to calculate the difference in hours, minutes and seconds, just do the usual math on `Calendar#getTimeInMillis()`.

Long story short, I've posted a basic example before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567659/calculate-elapsed-time-in-java-groovy/1776721#1776721). You may find it useful.