# How to calculate elasped time in Java from a provided hour ONLY

Tags: java, time, calendar, date

There are two parts to this: first compute the start date. Then compute the elapsed time. For the second part, I found some good advice here: [Calculate elapsed time in Java / Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567659/calculate-elapsed-time-in-java-groovy)

However, the first part is a problem for me. Here's how it works:
The user indicates that the time span extends from an hour value (00 to 23). I do not have a starting date/time object of any sort - just an integer hour. From that I need to figure the start date (and then the elapsed time).

If the start hour is greater than the now hour, it was the prior day. In order to get an actual start date from that however, I need to potentially consider month and year boundaries as well as things like leap years and daylight savings time changes. Surely someone has solved a problem like this already. (I believe it can be quite complex.) Is there a proven solution that will let me compute how much time (in seconds) has actually elapsed from the given hour of the day (00 to 24) to now? (The start time will always be assumed to be on the hour.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest using the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) API. It's the best date/time API available for Java, in my opinion.

Next you need to work out *exactly* what to do in various corner cases. In particular, suppose the user enters "1" and you're near a daylight saving transition. It's possible that 1am happened *twice* (if the the time went 1:58, 1:59, 1:00, 1:01 because of a transition back away from DST) or that it didn't happen at all (if the time went 12:58, 12:59, 2:00 because of a transition forward into DST). You need to work out what to do in each of those situations - and bear in mind that this means knowing the time zone too.

Once you've worked that out, it may not be too hard. With Joda Time you can use `withHourOfDay` method to get from one time to another having set one component of the time - and likewise there are simple APIs for adding or subtracting a day, if you need to. You can then work out the time between two `DateTime` values very easily - again, Joda Time provides everything you need.

Here's an example which doesn't try to do anything with DST transitions, but it's a good starting point:

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Defaults to current time and time zone
        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        DateTime then = now
            .withHourOfDay(hour)
            .withMinuteOfHour(0)
            .withSecondOfMinute(0);
        if (then.isAfter(now))
        {
            then = then.minusDays(1);
        }
        Period period = new Period(then, now, PeriodType.seconds());

        System.out.println("Difference in seconds: " + period.getSeconds());
    }
}
```

Comment: Joda Time ++ :) They are thinking of putting that JSR in the JDK 7!

Comment: @Mohamed: JSR310 is somewhat different to Joda Time, although they have the same main author.

Comment: sorry :x Stephen explained in his blog why he has both  http://www.jroller.com/scolebourne/entry/why_jsr_310_isn_t 

For JSR310 you use the javax.time.Duration class and can use the updated Calendar, and Date classes, so cool :)

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4290683/10819573) has provided a solution using Joda-Time API which was probably the best 3rd party date-time API in Java at that time. In Mar 2014, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the Java 8 standard library. Notice the following message on the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time`
> (JSR-310).

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern date-time API**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample hour indicated by the user
        int hour = 16;

        // Replace the ZoneId with the applicable one
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZonedDateTime then = LocalDate.now(zone)
                                      .atStartOfDay(zone)
                                      .withHour(hour);

        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
        System.out.println(now);

        if (then.isAfter(now))
            then = then.minusDays(1).withHour(hour);

        long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(then, now);
        System.out.println(seconds);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run**:

```
2023-01-08T09:31:28.040819-05:00[America/New_York]
63088
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/c4iiCf)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for providing the modern way to do this. To take all corner cases into account you may want: (1) give the same time zone to `LocalDate.now()` as to `atStartOfDay()`; (2) when you need to go one day back, repeat the entire procedure for finding the time since if the hour was 1 or 2, that hour might not have existed today but would then still exist yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable feedback. The first one was a miss which I could have caught had I reviewed my post. The second one is a very important consideration. I've updated the post now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `startHour` is given by the user (assume, that's in the 0-23 range). Now you may start with this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
...
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
if (start.get(HOUR_OF_DAY) < startHour) {
start.add(DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) classes. You can do something like this:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime start;
int startHour = getStartHour();// user's choice
int nowHour = now.getHourOfDay();
if (nowHour < startHour) {
  start = now.minusHours(24 - startHour + nowHour);
} else {
  start = now.minusHours(nowHour - startHour);
}
```