# Android/Java Time difference ISO 8601 with Now

Tags: java, android

I have an ISO 8601 time string and want to calculate the time difference to now in minutes without using joda time. How is this done?

Thanks

Comment: And a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/567659/642706) and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get a `Date`, get the milliseconds-since-unix-epoch of that using `Date.getTime()`, then compare with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

If your ISO-8601 strings contain a time zone offset as something like "-08:00" (which they certainly *can*), you'll need to remove the colon first, and use the `Z` format specifier in `SimpleDateFormat`. (In Java 7 you could use `X`, but that's not available in Android's version of `SimpleDateFormat` as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: Note that I had to drop the "Z" in the SimpleDateFormat format for things to work.

Answer (score 0):

What about javax.xml.datatype.Duration as returned by javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory?

Comment: Never mind: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14379

Comment: I ended up copying the file org/apache/axis/types/Duration.java, with a few modifications.