# SimpleDateFormat converting UTC to timezone incorrectly

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when converting the following ISO string `2017-09-01T01:00:00.000Z` into a date.

I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat stringToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date date = stringToDate.parse("2017-09-01T01:00:00.000Z");
```

The date object output has a date that looks like this

```
Fri Sep 01 01:00:00 MDT 2017
```

When I should get an output of

```
Fri Sep 01 01:00:00 UTC 2017
```

OR

```
Fri Aug 31 19:00:00 MDT 2017
```

It looks like it is not doing the timezone conversion correctly because the time is unchanged, but the timezone has been when neither or both should be changed.

Comment: Also dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9735426/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20322545/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25538918/642706) and many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The single quotes around the `'Z'` mean that it's not interpreted as a time zone specifier for UTC: it's simply a literal `Z` in the string, which is discarded.

   As you are not setting a timezone specifically on the `SimpleDateFormat`, the date is parsed in your JVM's default timezone.
2. `Date.toString()` uses your JVM's default timezone. There is no timezone in a `Date`. If you want to print in a specific timezone, you need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to print it.

Comment: Thank you.  I misunderstood the parsing of SimpleDateFormat. A few stackoverflow answers made it sound like it was telling SimpleDateFormat that it was in UTC.  But if it's just discarded, this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the java.time classes for handling dates in modern Java.

Date doesn't store a timezone, and Date.toString() uses the system default timezone when rendering.

Comment: I would if I could.  Android development is still transitioning over to Java 8 from Java 7

Comment: You can use joda-time, or the ThreeTenABP project (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to achieve much of the same thing (though they have downsides)

Comment: I've debated using Joda just to save me some of the headache of using these old libraries.  I'm trying to keep things light on libraries I'm pulling in, but it may be worth it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this function call to create `Calendar` instance, it should support *yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ* format.

`Calendar cal = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(ymd);`

edit: hmm you said Android ok this class may not be available.