# Java: date difference

Tags: java, date

I am working on dates in Java. I am finding out the difference between two dates.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Date futDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0).getTime();

    final Date currentDate = new GregorianCalendar().getTime();

    long diff = Math.round((futDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()) / 1000);

    System.out.println(diff / 86400 + " days");
    System.out.println((diff % 86400) / 3600 + " hrs");
    System.out.println(((diff % 86400) % 3600) / 60 + " mins");
    System.out.println((((diff % 86400) % 3600) % 60) % 60 + " secs");
}
```

Output:

```
31 days
8 hrs
37 mins
30 secs
```

Even though the date difference is less than a day, the output is more than 31 days.

Comment: Maybe a couple of system.out or just debugging the application could have helped you out.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/567659/642706

Answer (score 8, accepted):

8 isn't current month number :)

months are **numbered from 0**

Java's dates are painful, so I suggest take a look at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: And that's why we have constants for this: Calendar.AUGUST (which is 7) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#AUGUST

Comment: oh... Thx! I am using Calendar.AUGUST as suggested by duffymo.

Comment: @rahul, good for you. remember that days start from 1 and months start from 0. That's just java... ;]

Comment: That's not just Java. Many languages/API do it this way (which of course does not make it any better).

Comment: @Thilo I suppose it came from C, and was left that way in Java as well, as it was common way to do it... Anyway, common doesn't mean good.

Comment: @Thilo: More *modern* platforms tend to be saner, in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

Better yet, use the built in constants:

```
Calendar.AUGUST
```

Comment: Not that this is really useful, unless you are really hardcoding AUGUST into your code. Normally, you need to parse input data. Of course, DateFormat handles that.

Comment: Just answering the question as stated, Thilo.  Of course it's not typical.

Answer (score 3):

> I am working on dates in Java.

You'd be *much* better off using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)

> I am finding out the difference between two dates.

Joda Time makes this really easy:

```
LocalDateTime start = ...;
LocalDateTime end = ...;
Period period = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.dayTime());

System.out.println(period.getDays() + " days");
System.out.println(period.getHours() + " hrs");
System.out.println(period.getMinutes() + " mins");
System.out.println(period.getSeconds() + " secs");
```

Comment: You still need to set the months in start and end correctly, though.

Comment: @Thilo: True, but Joda Time uses sane bases :)

Answer (score 0):

The month is 0 based as described in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

So you might want to set it to 7 instead of 8.

Also for duration calculation there is [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) a IMO pretty sophisticated time API.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted Answer by [dantuch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949859/642706) is correct. The `GregorianCalendar` class has crazy numbering of months 0-11 for January-December.

## Using java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes such as `GregorianCalendar` are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

Most importantly, the java.time classes use sane numbering for months, 1-12 for January-December. And the [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum makes working with months even more explicit and less error-prone.

You are ignoring the issue of time zone in determining a date. Your code implicitly uses the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can change at any time by a call from any code in any thread of any app within the JVM. Better to be explicit about your desired/expected time zone.

Also, you assume the day starts at the time `00:00:00`. That is not always true because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 8 , 15 );
```

…or…

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.AUGUST , 15 );
```

Let java.time determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtThen = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

Get the current moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Get elapsed time with the `Duration` class for days-hours-minutes-seconds or `Period` for years-months-days.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtThen , zdtNow );
```

No automatic way to build your desired string. In Java 9 and later you can extract the parts to build your own string: `toDaysPart`, `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart`, and `toSecondsPart`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).