# Time difference with Server time and SystemTime android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I am working on android application where i am getting date from server like : `Thu Jul 02 14:18:58 GMT+04:00 2015` and after parsing it through SimpleDateFormat i am getting it like: Thursday , July 02 , 2015 02:18 PM. And through `Calender.getTime()` i am getting the time `Thu Jul 02 14:57:25 GMT+04:00 2015` and after parsing it i am getting `Thursday , July 02 , 2015 02:57 PM`. Now i just need to take the time difference between two date and times. I was doing like the following thing but it is giving me NumberFormat Exception. Please help me out here.

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE , MMMM dd , yyyy hh:mm a");
        String systemTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        int lastLocationSyncInt = Integer.parseInt(lastLocationSync);
        int systemTimeInt = Integer.parseInt(systemTime);
        int lastSeenTimeDifference =  systemTimeInt -lastLocationSyncInt ;
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setSnippet(lastSeenTimeDifference+"");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate elapsed time in Java / Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567659/calculate-elapsed-time-in-java-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting into Integer, format in date and get the difference as like below

```
long days = 0;
        long hours = 0;
        SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEEE , MMMM dd , yyyy hh:mm a");
        Date sDate = null;
        Date sEdate = null;
        try {
            sDate = sourceFormat.parse(startdate);
            sEdate = sourceFormat.parse(enddate);

            long diff = sDate.getTime() - sEdate.getTime();
            long seconds = diff / 1000;
            long minutes = seconds / 60;
            hours = minutes / 60;
            days = hours / 24;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

if you have any doubt feel free to comment

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, can you please help me out to sort this. I am getting  Minutes: 62 and Seconds: 3905 like this.

Comment: do you want date difference in days or minute or seconds??

Comment: In all of three. I want the difference.in separate variables.