# Get time difference between date string to current date in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time

I have a date string looking like this:

```
String time1 = "2018-08-28T10:23:25.617Z";
```

I want to get the difference between this date to the current date in utc time. What is the easiest way to do it? thanks.

Comment: [Java string to date conversion](//stackoverflow.com/q/4216745)

Comment: Please use your search engine. I’m sure you can find questions and answer that match your exact requirements better than what we have found and linked to. It’s not clear whether you want the difference in days or in milliseconds or something else.

Comment: Search before posting. This topic has been addressed many many times already. You can assume any basic date-time question has been asked and answered.

Comment: Also duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1770010/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/567659/642706)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8405087/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque Most of the answers to the "duplicated questions" are using 'SimpleDateFormat' which is legacy, and also didn't work for me. And also, I think one person that says it's duplicate is enough, no need to 'duplicate' previous comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.time.Instant` and `java.time.Duration`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2018-08-28T10:23:25.617Z"); // start time in UTC
Instant now = Instant.now();  // end time in UTC

Duration duration = Duration.between(instant, now); // the Duration

System.out.println(duration.toSeconds()); // duration in seconds
```