# extract date time then compare with previous datetime

Tags: datetime, groovy

I want to make sure the date time stored in database table is not more than 2 minutes than previous captured date time.

the result returned from Database table is in this format.

```
[[col1:2020-05-28 04:02:21.34]]
```

**my codes**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
//capture current date time
def date = new Date()
println date.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SS',TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))

//wait 2 minutes then capture DB table date time
WebUI.delay(120)
PostgresdbQuery = /SELECT col1 FROM table1.test/
List resultsafter = CustomKeywords.'test.database.getPostgresSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.testPostgresdbConnString , GlobalVariable.testPostgresdbUsername , GlobalVariable.testPostgresdbPassword ,GlobalVariable.testPostgresdbDriver ,PostgresdbQuery )
println(resultsafter)

//assert 
assert resultsafter < date, 'Execute time is within 2 minutes'
```

**error**

```
Reason:
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[{col1=2020-05-28 04:02:21.34}]' and java.util.Date with value '5/28/20 1:49 PM'
```

Comment: Use TimeCategory and TimeDuration for accurate time calculations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2757551/3355860

Comment: @ou_ryperd 
Saw the time duration, but I couldn't make it right still like below minus calculation. 
TimeDuration td = TimeCategory.minus( resultsafter, date )
println td // after this td, how do make sure its within 2 minutes? Using assertion or any time syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The result is a list of maps. To make that check work, you would have to write it as:

```
assert resultsAfter.first().col1 < date
```

This will only work for the very first result and only if there is one.  Assuming, you want to assert that for all elements, you can use `every` or loop the results and do the asserts for each row.

Yet, at this point i'd just let the DB do the work: select all items, that **dont't** match the criteria and make sure, no results are found.

Comment: I saw this, will try it. assert resultsAfter.first().col1 == sdf.format(new Date() + 2.minutes